# How to let cable unplugging/re-plugging not affect the screen numbers in the program

Tags: c#, winforms, screen

This might be a silly question, but I could not find any information on this. Is there any way to display a specific form to a specific monitor?

I am making a WinForm application in C#, I need to make it not affected by the HDMI cable's disconnection and re-connection. I have 3 forms (A, B, and C), and Form A needs to be always displayed on monitorA, Form B on monitorB, and Form C on monitorC. I am currently assigning each form on each monitor like

```
FormA.Location = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Location; //screen 0 = monitor A
FormB.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location; //screen 1 = monitor B
FormC.Location = Screen.AllScreens[2].WorkingArea.Location; //screen 2 = monitor C
```

This works fine until I disconnect the cable(s) and reconnect them. Sometimes, it doesn't affect the program, but sometimes, disconnecting and re-connecting the cables changes the screen number assigned to each monitor, and messes up the screen configuration. Like Form A is displayed on monitorC.

It seems like the screen number is assigned on the hardware side, but is there any way to fix the monitor-form relationship? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you infer the right screen from `Screen.AllScreens[x].DeviceName` using  `Screen.AllScreens.Count()` for the _x_ index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that is something that Windows does and isn't easily avoided. If you have an nVidia Pro graphics adapter, or another adapter that supports it, you can setup the graphics driver to load monitor EDID from a file instead of from the monitor and lock Windows into thinking the monitor is permanently connected. There may be other brands that support disabling monitor detection as well.